# how to use non-printable char as field separator of sort command in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

The sort command has a parameter "-t" to declare the fields separator instead of the default blank. For example:

```
sort -t 'a' file
```

what if I want to use a non-printable char as the spearator, like the fifth char in ASCII table ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a special quoting in bash, that can be used for this purpose. Try the following command and look for `$'...'` in the bash manual:

```
sort -t $'\05' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enter a non-printable character in bash (and also in vim) by using ctrl-V and then the non-printable control code. Thus, for character 0x04, Ctrl-V Ctrl-D inserts `^D`, which is a representation of the character 0x04.

Press:

```
sort -t '<ctrl-V><ctrl-D>' file
```

and this will be displayed:

```
sort -t '^D' file
```

Comment: it will not work always, because i use some key-binding in vim.

Comment: and when in shell, it  will not work always neither, because of some key-binding in my term.

Comment: Well, since everything is bindable in vim, I can only give you standard bindings. Also... why would you `imap` `<C-V>`?

Comment: Well, that's a way to solve! But exactly i'am an emacser, I use vim not very often.